# How to calculate field based on another fields

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, fields-attributes

I´m trying to calculate field based on another fields. I´ve got this attribute table. 
Example: If field "Smisenost" is S than FRST in new field. 
Example 2: If field "Smisenost" is NULL, if field "KULTURAKOD" is NULL, if field "ZpusobyVyu" is NULL, if "DruhPozemku" is 7 than RNGE.
Field "DruhPozemku" has always value, but another ones not. So I need script for calculate value from values that you can see in image.

[image]

It should work by this key. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just above the "k" in the last field name, you have the field calculator icon (an abacus). You can use it to type in more or less any possible formula to calculate a field. Make your new field "Text (string)". Use a virtual field if the calculation is not too heavy or make a new (or reuse an existing) field if you want to save the data in the data set. (To make a new non-virtual field, you need to have access to edit the data set.)

For your first example, the expression should be

```
if("Smisenost" = 's','FRST','')
```

For the second

```
if("Smisenost" is NULL and "KULTURAKOD" is NULL and 
  field "ZpusobyVyu" is NULL and  "DruhPozemku" = 7,'RNGE','')
```

Or should those expressions calculate for the same field? If so you need to "feed on" expressions in the results_when_false part. i.e

```
if("Smisenost" = 's','FRST',
  if("Smisenost" is NULL and "KULTURAKOD" is NULL and 
    field "ZpusobyVyu" is NULL and  "DruhPozemku" = 7,'RNGE',''))
```

It may grow a bit unwieldy...

The expression editor will indicate if the expression is valid. Quite a few times, I have forgotten to set the right field type. If you do this and then try to e.g. put a string into an integer field, all field will have the value NULL. To correct this, you need to go into the field calculator, define a new field, remember to set the field type right and then you will find your last expression at the bottom at the search list beside the expression input box.

Comment: I edit my answer with table for clasification, is there any possibilities to make this more general? I mean, if i define that FRST = ´s´ in "Smisenost", RNGE = ´T´ in "KULTURAKOD" or  ˇ7´ in "DruhPozemku" for every single 4-letter code. 
Thank you.